# Prevent unflagging of an entity in event subscriber

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

An action in a node view is supposed to unflag the node. But when a certain condition is met, I want to prevent unflagging of the node. I tried flagging the node again in the event subscriber method but it's too early in the method to flag it.

In event subscriber's

```
getSubscribedEvents():
```

```
$events[FlagEvents::ENTITY_UNFLAGGED] = ['onUnflag',11];
```

Inside the method:

```
if(//conditions met) {
        try {
          $flag_service->flag($generate_components_flag, $this->getEntity());
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
          file_put_contents("drupal_errors.txt", $e->getMessage());
        }
      }
```

yields:

> The user has already flagged the entity with the flag.